# How do I extend the storage space on a lvm filesystem in Linux?

Tags: linux, lvm, gparted

I recently added CentOS 7 to my home PC alongside Windows 10 while WFH.

The amount of storage space I allocated for this ended up not being enough, so I used [Gparted](https://gparted.org/) to reduce my windows space and granted it to my CentOS partition. My drive now looks like this:

[image: GParted shows /dev/sdb]

sdb6 is my linux partition. All the space I made available to sdb6 is currently unused, but does not appear as available space according to nautilus.

[image: File manager shows filespace]

I've looked at some previous answers, but they appear not to apply to LVM based file systems. I found [this page on the RHEL website](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/logical_volume_manager_administration/lv_extend) that appears to be what I am looking for, but when I try their command:

```
sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/sdb6
```

I get this error:

```
"/dev/sdb6": Invalid path for Logical Volume.
```

How can I make these 34GB available for storage on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it for the disk not for lv.

Just do a `sudo lvs` command and based on the list of output LVs , you can use :

```
sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE <LV-Name>
```

Comment: doing sudo LVs reveals two different LVS:   the root and swap - out of precaution i allocated 1GB to the root and that task was apparently performed successfully - but upon checking nautilus and gparted I see no change in the allocated space.

Comment: running "sudo xfs_growfs /dev/centos_stephen/root" after running "sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/centos_stephen/root" appears to have worked - nautilus and gparted both are reporting the storage space I was hoping to get. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes , I forgot about increasing the filesystem as well ...Pleasure ...